# iptables REJECT icmp-admin-prohibited

Tags: linux-kernel, iptables, icmp

The iptables man page says:

> Using icmp-admin-prohibited with kernels that do not support it will result in a plain DROP instead of REJECT

I have been unsuccessful at finding out at **which kernel version** this became supported.   Does anyone know?

FWIW, the server I am interested in is running:

> 2.6.18-409.el5 #1 SMP Fri Feb 12 06:37:28 EST 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A look through one of the online kernel source browsers suggests it was supported in 
[2.4.37](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_REJECT.c?v=2.4.37#L356) at least, as this netfilter code seems to be implementing this  reject.

It seems the info was added to the iptables man pages in [may 2003](http://git.netfilter.org/iptables/commit/iptables.8?id=5a52c517ebb2c7421f57b0f00f2de6697cdd7a9c).